# Is there a way to repeat an event in django or make a recurring one?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to make a **recurring** event that repeat every weak or month. I've searched a lot but I didn't find an answer.
models.py

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author  = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=("author"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body    = models.TextField()
    date    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to make **date** field repeated.

Comment: Question is a bit confusing. You need a recurring event(eg. repeating a particular task) or you need the same date in each Event object...??

Comment: I need a recurring event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Django Management Command to write the event you want to take place and schedule it (daily/weekly/monthly) with crontab. You may refer to the following tutorial for more details: [Django Management Command + Crontab](https://blog.khophi.co/django-management-commands-via-cron/).

Alternatively, you may use Celery for periodic tasks. For further details, you may refer to: [Celery Docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)